# How to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}tr(BXX^tA)$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

I know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}tr(BXX^t) = BX + B^tX$ according to the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) equation 109.

However, I need to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}tr(BXX^tA)$. Is there a simple way to derive this formula from the previous one?

Comment: Use $\operatorname{tr}(BXX'A)=\operatorname{tr}(ABXX')$?

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!

Comment: When is $\operatorname{tr}(CD)=\operatorname{tr}(DC)$ true and when is it not?

Comment: On a second thought, what if dimensions of A and B don't agree?

Comment: If X is $n \times p$, then B and A are $? \times n$, so we can't necessarily have $AB$?

Comment: In that case $XX^T$ is $n\times n\;$ as are $A$, $B$, and $AB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace is traditionally defined for a square matrix. Assuming that is the case, let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$. Then by commutative property of trace

\begin{align*}
tr(BXX^{\top}A) = tr(ABXX^{\top}) = tr(CXX^{\top})
\end{align*}

for $C = AB \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. From there, you can directly apply the derivative equation. The definition of trace and its commutative property should be easily encountered by any math or applied math major ;)